# git rebase --interactive throws an error

Tags: macos, shell, git, xcode

I'm relatively new to git. Could anyone, please, help running `git rebase --interactive` properly? It throws an error when I try to execute it.

**Note**: I don't want to uninstall Xcode unless it's inevitable (because some packages require it's tools to compile).

Here's the error:

`$ git rebase -i
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: line 234: -w: command not found
Could not execute editor`

This file, of course, exists, is an executable shell script and has no `--help` option.

`git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an editor configured properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits

Comment: Tangentially, you can use `[0-9]` instead of `[0123456789]`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks, worked for me. didn't suspect it to be so easy.

Comment: If you have an answer, make it an answer. ;) That being said, I recommend using the Git version available via [brew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: @DanielB You mean me or glenn jackman? Isn't it quite shizo-like to answer questions u ask?

Comment: [Answering your own questions is encouraged](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) -- imagine someone who found your question through google: it would be good to provide that person your solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that my `git rebase -i` wasn't told what editor to use. Thus, it is fixed by setting one.

Let's claim that out editor is `vim` (or `nano`, or w/e). Then either

`export GIT_EDITOR=vim` (global)

or

`git config --global core.editor "vim"` (local)

Would solve the problem.

**Credit** goes to glenn jackman https://superuser.com/users/4714/glenn-jackman

**Related question**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits